pre-commit autoupdate C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4up095pz\.pre-commit-hooks.yaml is not a file
Need some help desperately now:
I am creating a pre-commit hook to trigger dotnet format tool when git commit -m ""
And I have a p.re-commit-config.yaml file right inside the solution root folder that can be reached by pre-commit autoupdate
since the repo's one of our microservice component
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/**/Exchange
    rev: daa6bb69960b1e4d120cffb1f307afb9c5b493c1 #generated the latest SHA with pwsh update_rev.ps1
    hooks:
      - id: update-and-commit
        name: Update rev and commit
        entry: | 
          Write-Host "Starting update_rev.ps1 script..."
          ./.update_rev.ps1 
          Write-Host "Calling Update-Config function..."
          Update-Config -ConfigFile "./.pre-commit-config.yaml" 
          Write-Host "Executing git add..." 
          git add "./pre-commit-config.yaml" 
          Write-Host "Executing git commit..." 
          git commit       
        language: script
        pass_filenames: false 

      - id: dotnet-format
        name: Format C# files using dotnet format
        entry: Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj | ForEach-Object {
                 Write-Host "Reading $_.FullName"
                 dotnet format --verbosity normal $_.FullName
               }
        language: system 
        types: [c#]

And the update_rev.ps1 is:
function Update-Config {
    param ($ConfigFile)
    Write-Host "$ConfigFile"
    # Get latest commit SHA on the 'main' branch 
    $latestSHA = git rev-parse main 2>$null
    $latestSHA
    
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "Failed to retrieve the latest commit SHA. Please ensure you are on the 'main' branch."
        exit 1
    }

    # Read the YAML config file
    $configText = Get-Content -Path $ConfigFile

    # Replace the 'rev' value (Modify if your config structure differs)
    $updatedConfig = $configText -replace '(?<=rev:\s).*', $latestSHA 

    # Overwrite the config file
    $updatedConfig | Set-Content -Path $ConfigFile
} 

# Call the function with the path to the config file
$configFilePath = "./.pre-commit-config.yaml" 
Update-Config -ConfigFile $configFilePath --force

I have tried a few ways around (check directory,clean cache, uninstall/install pre-commit) but the error output still:
=====> C:\Users\username\.cache\pre-commit\repoh63ihe8q\.pre-commit-hooks.yaml is not a file
or 
=====> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpui9t9p_t\.pre-commit-hooks.yaml is not a file

the /pre-commit and /Temp folder exist, but the file is not created and not in that directory as well.
How to know if I have permission to access that /pre-commit cache folder and create the .pre-commit-hooks.yaml file?
I suspect it's the rev SHA is not correct so it cannot access the folder but I don't know how to find out.
The log file is as:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\error_handler.py", line 73, in error_handler
    yield
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\main.py", line 417, in main
    return run(args.config, store, args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\commands\run.py", line 425, in run
    for hook in all_hooks(config, store)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\repository.py", line 242, in all_hooks
    return tuple(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\repository.py", line 245, in <genexpr>
    for hook in _repository_hooks(repo, store, root_config)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\repository.py", line 220, in _repository_hooks
    return _cloned_repository_hooks(repo_config, store, root_config)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pre_commit\repository.py", line 187, in _cloned_repository_hooks
    by_id = {hook['id']: hook for hook in load_manifest(manifest_path)}
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\cfgv.py", line 416, in load_from_filename
    return apply_defaults(data, schema)
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\cfgv.py", line 45, in reraise_as
    raise tp(e).with_traceback(tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\cfgv.py", line 42, in reraise_as
    yield
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\cfgv.py", line 401, in load_from_filename
    raise ValidationError(f'{display_filename} is not a file')
pre_commit.clientlib.InvalidManifestError: 
=====> C:\Users\username\.cache\pre-commit\repoecyb86_3\.pre-commit-hooks.yaml is not a file


@Filburt  it's right, this file is .pre-commit-config.yaml, it can be reached and read

the error indicates that at the latest tagged revision of whatever https://github.com/**/Exchange is -- that there is no pre-commit manifest
I suspect that the manifest only exists on newer tagged versions -- you could use pre-commit autoupdate --bleeding-edge -- or if you control that repo you can make a release

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Thank you for the answer. our latest version say is 0.4.1 even i initially put rev: v0.4.1 it didn't work , atter running pre-commit autoupdate --bleeding-edge, the same error, it looks like the latest SHA couldn't be caught by the outcome of update_rev.ps1? how to achieve this?Thank you so much!

do you have a remote repository with hooks configured? I think you're confusing the .pre-commit-hooks.yaml and . pre-commit-config.yaml.  maybe you want repo: local? though that kind of defeats the purpose of the framework

Thank you a ton @Anthony you are so right! It should be repo: local after that everything works!!! My highest respect for saving another couple of hours work!

For people who also have the same problem the code should be:
`repos:

repo: local`

The rev tag will be exempted
